# MFMailComposeViewController crash when pressing "Delete Draft"

Tags: xcode, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a button that call a MFMailComposeViewController. Sometimes, when I click "delete draft", the app crashes but sometimes it correctly dismiss the view. I can' understand why. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)openEmail:(id)sender {
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = (id)self;
    NSArray *myEmail = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"me@gmail.com", nil];
    [composer setToRecipients:myEmail];
    [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:nil];
    [[composer navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.843 green:0.435 blue:0.435 alpha:1]];
}
else {

   }
}
```

and this method:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");

        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved");

        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail send");

        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail failed");

        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");

        break;
}
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I used to experience this as well, and the potential problematic area in your code may be this line:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

It's likely that by the time `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` methods are called, your `composer` object is deallocated. Instead, try initiating `MFMailComposeViewController` on a strong property, like so:

```
self.composer = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
```

You can set `self.composer` to `nil` once you have acted on the delegate methods to release the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
[self presentModalViewController:_picker animated:YES];
```

Notice 'MODAL'?

With also:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```